# Composite Primary Key in PyMODM

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoModel subclass called User, I want to make the combination of name and phone number (two fields in the class) the primary key.

Using pymongo something like `{"_id": {"name": "test_name", "phone_number": 1234}}` can be done, but couldn't find how to do something like this using PyMODM.

When I try to set the kwarg `primary_key=True` for multiple fields but that gives the error saying `mongo_name cannot be same for multiple fields.`